# I'm looking for a short story about super intelligent/ Telepathic children

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I don't remember the story exactly but I know it has to do with an experiment or discovery that made a group of children extremely intelligent or telepathic.  I don't exactly remember the plot all the way but I remember the military got involved causing a conflict and the group ended the conflict by placing themselves 1 second in the future of the resolve of the world.  The area they did it in was in a remote forest and the area became an orb because of the time change.

Thanks

Comment: See you added a comment below that it was a short story.  About when was this published or when did you read it ?  Do you recall if it was in an anthology of some sort ?

Answer (score 17):

How about [The First Men](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_First_Men) by Howard Fast.  Sci Fi short published in 1960 in The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction.  Text is now freely available online - [Full Text](http://trussel.com/hf/firstmen.htm)

The excerpt below from the text is what makes me think it's the story you're interested in.  It tracks quite closely to your reference of them placing themselves one second in the future.

> We got the three years we needed, and as for the gray barrier that surrounds us, the children tell me that it is a simple device indeed. As nearly as I can understand, they altered the time sequence of the entire reservation. Not much -- by less than one ten thousandth of a second. But the result is that your world outside exists this tiny fraction of a second in the future. The same sun shines on us, the same winds blow, and from inside the barrier, we see your world unaltered. But you cannot see us. When you look at us, the present of our existence has not yet come into being -- and instead there is nothing, no space, no heat, no light, only the impenetrable wall of non-existence.

Comment: YES this is it 
Thank you so much

Comment: @ace6 - It would be helpful if you accept the answer as correct.

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/182062/4918 for another story-identification question with the same answer.

Answer (score 4):

On the assumption that you could be misremembering some details, the story *could* be the "blue children" part of the novel [Manifold: Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold%3a_Time) by Stephen Baxter.

Comment: No it is definitely a short story but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could it be The Midwich Cuckoos by John Wyndham?

[http://www.amazon.com/Midwich-Cuckoos-John-Wyndham/dp/0899683878](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0899683878)

Comment: Don't think this is the novel. 'The Midwich Cuckoos' was the basis for both versions of 'Village of the Damned'. In the book and the 1960 movie, all the children are killed by a bomb.  There's no treatment of anything involving time displacement and the children don't survive. The 1995 movie is essentially the same except one child (David) survives at the end.  That's a deviation from the book though.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact match but parts of it sound like [More Than Human](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_Than_Human) by Theodore Sturgeon.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Could you add a brief summary of this story, e.g. by quoting from the link, so that we can judge how well it matches the OP's question and so that this isn't just a "link-only answer"?