# Children are being born with psychic powers, leaving the adults behind

Tags: story-identification

Looking for the title of a book or story where children are being born with psychic powers, leaving the adults behind. I read it probably around 1990 so it was before then.

The gist was that the kids were evolving quickly and leaving.

Comment: Childhood's End might be right - but more details would help ensure that. Do you recall any thing else about the book?  Are all children suddenly born with powers, or does it start with a few?

Comment: Depending how old the kids are, this could even apply to "Dr. Pak's Preschool."

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/182060/short-story-genius-children-raised-in-institution-invent-many-things-and-isol

Answer (score 14):

Could it be [Childhood's End](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Childhood%27s_End), by Arthur C. Clarke?

> As Rashaverak explains, the time of humanity as a race composed of
> single individuals with a concrete identity is coming to an end. The
> children's minds reach into each other and merge into a single vast
> group consciousness. If the Pacific were to be dried up, the islands
> dotting it would lose their identity as islands and become part of a
> new continent; in the same way, the children cease to be the
> individuals which their parents knew and become something else,
> completely alien to the "old type of human".

Comment: Yes I think that was it- thank you!